# About tail recursion

Tags: c, tail-recursion

Recently I am reading Mastering Algorithms with c, and in this book I have 1 exercise that I am not able to implement with c.

```
Tn = 1             if n=1 ,
Tn = 2T(n/2) + n   if n > 1
```

Anyone can help me? I'll appreciate it a lot.

I have tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test(int n) {
if (n == 1)
  return 1;
else if( n > 1 )
  return test(n / 2) * 2 + n;
}

int testtail(int n, int running_result) {
  if (n == 1)
    return running_result;
  else
    **return testtail(n / 2, ???? );** // How can I implement the second param
}
```

I am sorry guys! I am not a native English speaker! Maybe I made some mistakes in grammer! I should apologize for this!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What went wrong?

Comment: asking for doing homework... that too without showing any efforts...

Comment: Please try some code. If you run into issues, post the code and explain where you think there is a problem.

Comment: This is a very bad example for tail recursion ... I would have a hard time solving this, too.

Comment: testtail() doesn't need to be recursive, just loop through values of n and call test() to see what it returns.

Comment: Haha! I suspect too. But since it is an exercise in the chapter on resursion, it should be solved with recursion even though the implement is not required in the book.

Comment: Like that: http://ideone.com/AUXCqN

Comment: Thank you all the same! Your coder are more rigorous.